# addToSet for an array in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this sample document:

```
> db.sample.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570f76ca4fe66c8ae29f13cd"),
    "a" : [
        {
            "b" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "b" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "b" : [
                4
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to add the number 4 to `b` array for each instance in the `a` array

I had hoped that

```
db.sample.update({},{$addToSet:{"a.b":4}})
```

would do the trick, but this yields the error:

```
cannot use the part (a of a.b) to traverse the element ({a: [ { b: [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ] }, { b: [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ] }, { b: [ 4.0 ] } ]})
```

Is such a update possible?  Obviously I can pull each document to the client side update and replace, but that's really only a last resort.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do the equivalent of this                  `db.sample.update({},{$addToSet:{a[0].b:4, a[1].b:4, a[2].b:4}})`. You would have to go through each item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like until [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) Jira is implemented, you'll have to do it one-by-one for each item in the array, e.g.:

```
db.sample.update({},{$addToSet:{"a.0.b":4}})
db.sample.update({},{$addToSet:{"a.1.b":4}})
```

If you only need to update first element you could have used:

```
db.sample.update({},{$addToSet:{"a.$.b":4}})
```

Comment: The comments in the link you provided certainly make for "interesting" reading.  More to the point, using the $ operator, in my specific case, has saved the day. Thanks!